# Are physics conference abstracts ever screened?

Tags: conference, abstract

Do conferences ever reject low quality abstracts? I've never heard of anybody wanting to attend conferences and being rejected.

If they do screen abstracts, will they reject abstracts that are not of low quality but are too broad in theme? Will organizers give applicants a chance to revise abstracts?

Comment: Could you clarify more? The conferences I know may accept or reject *papers*, and the abstract is part of the paper, so it is evaluated together with it.

Comment: In my field, few people submit conference papers, which are of negligible imporance compared to journal papers. Abstracts are enough to attend conferences.

Comment: Can you link to one such conference. What you describe seems very foreign to many of us in other fields. A description that gives a hint about what happens. More than a "meet and greet" I suspect, but less than what happens at a CS conference, I think.

Comment: Most of the rejection are in reality acceptance as poster. This is how it works in practice in fields like physics, chemistry, material science etc. Not sure about other fields in which a poster is hard to conceive (for me at least).

Comment: This question is essentially unanswerable without a field (or perhaps even conference) specified.  I know of conferences where most applicants are purposefully rejected to maintain prestige, and others where abstracts are barely even type-set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Major physics conferences do not screen abstracts.  Abstracts that are nonsensical are routinely accepted at certain very big conferences.

Small conferences may vary.

Physics conferences do not permit revision of abstracts.

Comment: Some major physics conferences do screen abstracts. It depends a lot on the conference.

Comment: @mmeent Like what conferences? APS March?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the conference. Small conferences often accept most of things, at least to the poster stage.

In some fields, a conference is a place for researchers to meet, so conference papers have little significance.

In others, conference papers are almost as important as journal papers and its really hard to get an abstract in. [Check ICCV acceptance rates.](https://github.com/hoya012/ICCV-2019-Paper-Statistics). ICCV2019 accepted 25% of the papers only.

In any case, I doubt any conference would accept an abstract without checking it first. One thing is having low acceptance threshold and another is not checking the abstracts.

In short: it highly depends on the conference.

Comment: In physics, conference papers do not have "little significance" because they don't exist.

Comment: I see the question changed.